# How to select rows that don't have value in a second table

Tags: mysql

Basically I have a main table (accounts) and a meta table (accounts_meta)... The meta table looks like this:

```
id | account_id | meta_key | meta_value
```

What I want to do is only select accounts that do not have 'referrer_paid' as a row in the accounts_meta table...

Here is my code so far...

```
SELECT a.* FROM accounts AS a
    LEFT JOIN accounts_meta AS am ON a.id = am.account_id AND am.meta_key != 'referrer_paid'
    WHERE a.account_referrer != ''
    GROUP BY a.id
```

Hopefully I am making sense. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tiny change from @lexu:

> ```
> SELECT * 
>   FROM accounts 
>  WHERE id NOT IN ( select account_id 
>                      from `account_meta_table` 
>                     where meta_key = 'referrer_paid'
>                   );
> ```

Comment: Thanks lexu and didxga :) Having meta_key = 'referrer_paid' worked instead of the meta_key != 'referrer_paid'. Thank you both!

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM accounts 
 WHERE id NOT IN ( select DISTINCT account_id 
                     from `account_meta_table` 
                    where meta_key != 'referrer_paid'
                  );
```

Comment: thanx @lexu for proper indenting.

Comment: Left join is faster than subquery in mysql. Might be not so much difference in future when they improve optimizer (ver 6+).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a.* FROM accounts AS a
LEFT JOIN accounts_meta AS am ON a.id = am.account_id AND am.meta_key = 'referrer_paid'
WHERE a.account_referrer != ''
  AND am.account_id IS NULL
```

you dont need group by as left-join-is-null don't produce duplicate account rows

**EDIT:** duh, changed `am.meta_key != 'referrer_paid'` to `am.meta_key = 'referrer_paid'`

This is what you wanted.
It returns NULL for joined row if it doesnt match and you only take NULL rows

Answer (score 0):

SELECT a.* FROM accounts AS a
    LEFT JOIN accounts_meta AS am ON a.id = am.account_id AND am.meta_key != 'referrer_paid'
    WHERE ISNULL(am.account_referrer)
    GROUP BY a.id

Comment: you want to check for  ISNULL(am.account_id) in where clause instead.